# React-native offline package not working properly

Tags: react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

react-native offline package not working properly on continuous internet connection change.
My issue is,
https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline/issues/300

It updated with time delay,
Anyone faced this issue, please reply to this.

Comment: In emulator this package don't work properly with mobile network. When it turn off that network, it's detected but when it's turned on again then it isn't detected. However with Wifi it works well. I continue checking if I should do something more to get it fully working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with real device, its working fine. But not worked in emulator.